# Number of points of discontinuity of $f(x) = \int_0^x{t\sin{\frac1t}}dt$

Tags: definite-integrals, continuity

> **Question:**
>   Find the number of points of discontinuity of $f(x) = \int_0^x{t\sin{\frac1t}}dt$; for $x \in (0,\pi)$

I tried using By Parts assuming $t$ as first function,

$$\begin{align} \\ 
\int_0^x{t\sin{\frac1t}}dt &= \frac12x^2\sin\frac1x + \int_0^x{\frac12\cos{\frac1t}}dt \\ 
&=\frac12x^2\sin\frac1x + \frac x2\cos\frac1x - \frac12\int_0^x \frac1t\sin{\frac1t}dt
\end{align}$$

Now, it seems to be unsolvable *from  here.* I couldn't think of Newton-Leibniz, as it is helpful in case of differentiability. Any ideas?

---

The correct answer is:

> 0

Comment: Did your class go over the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: @minimalrho: No. But, I've got a little bit of its insight.

Comment: By fundamental theorem of calculus any integral function of the form $\int_a^xf(t) \, dt$ is continuous in $[a, b] $ if $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $$t \mapsto t\sin\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)$$ is continuous on $[0,\pi]$ so by the fundamental theorem of calculus $f$ is differentiable on $[0,\pi]$ and so continuous as well.

Comment: There is no need to check continuity of integrand $t\sin(1/t)$. The integral is always continuous whatever be the Integrand.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: are you saying that if the integrand be $\sin{\frac1t}$, would then also $f(x) = \int_0^x{\sin{\frac1t}}$  be differentiable?

Comment: No, what he is saying: For any riemann integrable function $g$ the function $$f(x) = \int_0^x g(t) dt$$ is continuous, no matter if $g$ is continuous itself or not.

Comment: @RahulVerma: I wanted to say exactly what Gono mentioned in his comment. However the example you chose is special. It can be proved with some effort using fundamental theorem of calculus that $f(x) =\int_0^x\sin(1/t)\,dt$ is differentiable everywhere with $f'(0)=0,f'(x)=\sin(1/x),x\neq 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x\in (0,\pi)$ and $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be an arbitrary sequence in $(0,\pi)$ converging to $x$. Then,

$$\left|\int_0^{x_n}{t\sin{\frac1t}}dt-\int_0^{x}{t\sin{\frac1t}}dt\right|$$

$$=\left|\int_x^{x_n}{t\sin{\frac1t}}dt\right|$$

$$\leq \left|\int_x^{x_n}{\left|t\sin{\frac1t}\right|}dt\right|$$

But as sine function is bounded by $1$ and $|t|$ is bounded by $\pi$, we get :

$$\leq \left|\int_x^{x_n}{\pi}dt\right|$$

$$= \pi\left|x_n-x\right|$$ which tends to zero as $n\to\infty$

Therefore as $x$ was arbitrary, by sequential criterion of continuity, $f$ is continuous on $(0,\pi)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, your answer seems to be a bit higher level for a 12 grade student (like me) to digest. Anyways I'll try my best to wrap my head around it :)